# htaccess redirection for #! in urls

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using ajax to load pages on my website.
Each time a page is loaded I change the url in the browser to

```
http//www.example.com/old/page/#!/new/page/
```

by setting it through window.loaction using javascript

Now what I want to do is when someone comes to my website by entering the url

```
http//www.example.com/old/page/#!/new/page/
```

he should automatically get redirected to

```
http//www.example.com/new/page/
```

This is somewhat that happens on facebook too.

Can someone help me out with the required .htaccess code to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anything past the # symbol in your URL is even visible on the server side.  So htaccess, php, etc won't even know the hash is there to begin with.  I think in order to pull this off you're going to have to use a client side redirect.

```
window.onload = function(){
  // First we use a regex to check for the #! pattern in the hash     
  if(window.location.hash.match(/\#\!/i)){
    // If we found a match, use substring to remove the #! and do a redirect
    window.location = window.location.hash.substring(2);
  }
};
```

This example will redirect the user immediately on page load. Unfortunately doing a redirect in this manner won't help the search engines to reindex your site, but thats just one of the pitfalls of using fancy javascript or hash based URL's.

Comment: i tried using hte following client script

requestedURL = ""+window.location+"";
position = requestedURL.search("#!");
domainame = "http://localhost"
if(position != -1){
 newpage = requestedURL.substr(position+2);
 requestedURL = "";
 window.location = domainame+newpage;
}

but the problem with this script was that it was being executed everytime a ajax call was made

Comment: it would be great if you could suggest some way of doing the same through javascript

Comment: Added an example. It worked on my web server but you may need to tweak it slightly to fit your environment.

Comment: i tried the code you have given above
but still facing the same problem that I had with my code

this code gets implemented every time I load any content even through ajax